# Bullseye: How to enable Bullseye for all processes

Tags: bullseye

From what little documentation I can find on the web, it seems that calling cov01 --on simply updates a user configuration file ($HOME/.BullseyeCoverage/UserSettings).  However, how can this be set more globally to intercept coverage for processes running as another user, all built using the same bullseye configuration file?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to call to `cov01` for any process you would like to use with Bullseye compiler interceptors. This is actually desired behavior because otherwise one process would determine the gcc behavior for all other processes.